# Stacking a minipage under two other minipages

Tags: floats, minipage

I am new to LaTeX and I am trying to write my thesis with it.
I am breaking my head on something that honestly looks very simple to solve, but I have not been able to figure out how to: I am trying to stack a minipage (with a figure inside) under two other minipages (with figures inside) in the same `figure` environment.

I would like for the overall composite figure to look like this:

[image]

with the caption at the bottom, but until now I have only this:

[image]

I did already try to insert just the two top images and it was working perfectly. Here there is the important part of my code:

```
\begin{figure}[!hbt]

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./3_introduction_aims/3_figures/pelegans_hp}

\end{minipage}

%

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./3_introduction_aims/3_figures/pvarians_hp}

\end{minipage}

%

\begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{./3_introduction_aims/3_figures/pserr_hq}

\end{minipage}

\caption{the three Palaemon species of Ireland. Top left: P. elegans; top right: P. varians; bottom: P. serratus (only females are illustrated; Hayward \& Ryland, 2017b).}

\label{fig1}

\end{figure}
```

While this is the code of my preamble (unimportant packages removed from the text):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: a blank line is a paragraph break so forces vertical stacking. Remove all the blank lines, you could also remove the minipages as they are not doing a lot and just have two `\includegraphics, a blank line then your third `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I actually tried before to just use the `\includegraphics` command, but for some reasons it was stacking them vertically, so I tried to use minipages and this way it initially worked. Nonetheless I will try again, seems simpler.

Comment: note for future questions "removing unimportant parts" is good but it's best to leave a complete document that shows the effect 9as in my answer) its a lot harder to debug fragments.

Answer (score 2):

Both `\includegraphics` and `minipage` have no positioning logic they just act like big letters in a paragraph, and as you have blank lines they are in separate paragraphs, so vertically stacked.

The `minipage` are not needed here, you just want three `\includegraphics`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering

\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}%
\hspace{.1\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image}%

\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{example-image}%

\caption{Three things}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you again @david

Comment: One of the top images is smaller in height than the other one. How can I push that one only up a bit, so its midline coincides with the midline of the other one?

Comment: easiest way is to add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` that adds some extra keys then add `,valign=m` to specify middle vertical alignment on the imaages @FrancescoGolin

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you again, that was very helpful!